# Convert Text in an Input to show as href links using comma split in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split text with comma and show them as links. I am converting them as as text but don't know how to convert them into links. I am using this code.

```
$('.tags').keyup(function() {
var ref = $('.tags').val();
var str_array = ref.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
   // Trim the excess whitespace.
   str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   // Add additional code here, such as:
$('.tag').html($(this).val());
}
});
```

What I am Getting is

```
<span class="tag">hello, world</span>
```

what I want is

```
<span class="tag"><a href="hello">hello</a>, <a href="world">world</a></span>
```

Comment: Is the `.tags` element `contenteditable`? I don't see how you could possibly cause a `keyup` event on it otherwise. Your code seems very confused, `span` elements don't have a value, and you're setting the HTML of the element to match the non-existant value... We can see the endpoint you're trying to get to, but the starting point is not clear. Are you working with a `span` or an `input`? Where does the value come from?

Comment: I suspect it's a plain input field

Comment: `$('.tag').html($(this).val());` this.val will always be the original, unmodified value.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the text in an basic input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is done with pure JS. No need for JQuery

```js
var tags = document.getElementById("tags");
tags.addEventListener("keyup", convert);

function convert() {
let tag = document.getElementById('tag');
tag.innerHTML = "";
let str = tags.value;
let res = str.split(",");
res.forEach(function(element, idx, array) {
let comma;
idx === array.length - 1 ? comma = '' : comma = ' , ';
let trimmedElement = element.trim();
tag.innerHTML += '<a href="'+ trimmedElement +'">'+ trimmedElement +'</a>'+ comma ;  
});
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tags">

<span id="tag"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom Marienfeld it worked but with a small problem of spacing. After typing "hello, world" the world becomes link with the space after the comma, can you add a trim function in it.

Comment: I added the trim() function. No more linked spaces :-)

Comment: This is the solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows in jQuery:

```
var ref = $('.tags').val();
var str_array = ref.split(',');
var tagLinks = '';

for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
   // Trim the excess whitespace.
   str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   tagLinks += '<a href="'+str_array[i]+'">'+str_array[i]+'</a>, ';
}

tagLinks = tagLinks.slice(0, -2);

$('.tag').html(tagLinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
// Element Selector
let selector = $(".tag");

// Get Text
let text = selector.text();

// Remove extra characters
text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/ig, '');

// Convert my text to array
let tags = text.split(" ");

// Empty the element
selector.html('');

// Append Tags
tags.forEach(function(tag){
    selector.append(`<a href="${tag}">${tag}</a> &nbsp;`)
});
```